# C# JsonConverter unable to deserialize object from JsonResult

Tags: c#, json

I have an API method witch returns model as json using my helper method

```
public static JsonResult ParseObjectToJsonResult<T>(T objectToParse) where T : class
{
    return new JsonResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToParse));
}
```

Then on the mobile side I am trying to deserialize this Json to the same model (simplified):

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>([string with response]);
```

Unfortunately I am getting an error and I am not sure why...

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value
>   "{"UserId":"00f0299f-3210-45bb-ab6f-5995de30bf26","IsSuccess":true,"Message":""}"
>   to type 'Models.APIResponseModels.LoginResponseModel'. Path '', line
>   1, position 91.

My model looks like :

```
JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserId")]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "IsSuccess")]
        public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [mcve]? I don't think you should need to use `JsonResult` for it - just serializing and deserializing may show it. Does this happen without a generic method? Also, it feels odd for your method to be called *Parse*Object, when you're *serializing* the value... they're opposites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
return new JsonResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToParse));
```

to

```
return new JsonResult(objectToParse);
```

You're double-serializing your data.  `JsonConvert` serializes it to a string, then `JsonResult` takes that string and serializes it *again*.

(Also, rename `objectToParse` to something else.  It isn't being parsed.  *Parsing* is the set of steps to turn a string into some kind of data structure.  You're going the other direction - a data structure to a string.)